# Only show unique edges in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I have an input file with about ~5000 lines and 1 to 9 nodes per line.

Many edges are not unique and I would like to only show the unique ones.

A more simple example.

```
graph {
    a -- b
    a -- b
    a -- b
}
```

Yields

[image]

Is there a way to make the above graph yield something like

[image]

I know I could change the sample input to

```
graph {
    a -- b
}
```

But it would not be easy to do that for my real input.

Comment: What's preventing you from eliminating the multi-edges just before producing the graphviz? Or from parsing graphviz and eliminating multi-edges? It would probably be fairly simple to do this with `igraph` in Python

Comment: If the graph is too large to parse through, it's *definitely* too large to visualize

Comment: @AlexReinking I could do it that way, but was wondering if there is a way to just have graphviz do the work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There actually is a way: Use the [`strict`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) keyword:

```
strict graph G {
    a -- b [label="First"];
    a -- b [label="Second"];
    a -- b [label="Third"];
}
```

Result:

[image: GraphViz output showing combined edges.]

Without `strict`, all three edges would be shown. Note that it only takes the first edge's attributes, contrary to what the documentation suggests.

Comment: yours is better, demonstrating the fact (and potential issue) with labels.

Answer (score 3):

Try `strict`:

```
strict graph {
    a -- b
    a -- b
    a -- b
}
```

This yields

[image]

and should work for any size of graph.

Comment: No way! We posted the same solution within a minute of each other!

Comment: I marked Alex's as answered as per your comment @vaettchen but appreciate your help as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to get a clean file, which doesn't contain any of the duplicate edges, you can use the graph processing tool `gvpr`.

Here is a snippet, which does just that:

```
BEG_G { graph_t g = graph($G.name,"U") }
E {
   node_t h = clone(g,$.head);
   node_t t = clone(g,$.tail);
   if(isEdge(t,h,"")==NULL){
      edge_t e = clone(g,$);
   }
}
END_G { $O = g; }
```

save this as something like `gvpr_rm_dupl_edges` and run `$ gvpr -f gvpr_rm_dupl_edges input.dot -o output.dot`. gvpr comes preinstalled with graphviz.

In case of directed graphs, change the `"U"` in the beginning of the code snippet to `"D"`

I wrote this snippet for a simple graph, without sub-graphs. It might not work on something more sophisticated.